# HAProxy nested ACL conditionals

Tags: haproxy

I have a set of the following defined within a **frontend**:

```
    acl abc_f path_beg /abc/
    use_backend abc if abc_f
```

Now, I'd like to direct a **domain** to a **backend**, and it should not have any of the above ACL conditions applied to it. I wanted add in:

```
acl host_xyz hdr(host) -i xyz.com
```

Is there anyway I can "nest" the ACL conditions so it only occurs on a specific domain, and not to the new domain?

Or do I have to modify each ACL rule to now take account of the domain?

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate multiple ACLs at once, but keep in mind that HAProxy uses short-circuit evaluation of the conditions (it stops evaluation at the moment it encounters false condition).

If I understood your question correctly, you wish to exclude domain xyz.com from `use_backend abc if abc_f` (i.e. you don't want to direct requests for domain xyz.com to backend **abc**). To do that, you can simply add an extra condition to **use_backend abc** directive:

```
acl abc_f path_beg /abc/
acl host_xyz hdr(host) -i xyz.com

# Use backend "abc" if ACL "abc_f" is true and if ACL "host_xyz" is not true
use_backend abc if abc_f !host_xyz
```